# Row number per group in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to produce query result base on this scenario that can create row number according to crew_id and type.

```
id   crew_id   amount    type
 1      4       1000      AUB
 2      4       1500      AUB
 3      5       8000      CA
 4      4       1000      CA
 5      5       1000      AUB
 6      6       3000      AUB
 7      4       2000      CA
 8      6       3500      AUB
 9      4       5000      AUB
 10     5       9000      CA
 11     5       1000      CA
```

OUTPUT must be the ff:

```
id    crew_id   amount   type    row_number
 1      4       1000      AUB        1    
 2      4       1500      AUB        2 
 9      4       5000      AUB        3
 4      4       1000      CA         1
 7      4       2000      CA         2
 5      5       1000      AUB        1
 3      5       8000      CA         1
 10     5       9000      CA         2
 11     5       1000      CA         3
 6      6       3000      AUB        1
 6      6       3000      AUB        2
```

I want a single select statement only in this output

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: All the answers break if you have more than table, force-subselect them: `SELECT ... CASE ... FROM (SELECT the real thing FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2) x`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The question is quite old. But I would like to post it in case someone will have a same problem.

First of all, described answers do not work correct. For example, for

```
id   crew_id   amount    type
1      4       1000      AUB
2      4       1500      AUB
5      5       1000      AUB
6      6       3000      AUB
8      6       3500      AUB
9      4       5000      AUB
```

(I just removed rows with type 'CA') the result table will be

```
id   crew_id   amount    rank   type
1      4       1000      1      AUB
2      4       1500      2      AUB
9      4       5000      3      AUB
5      5       1000      4      AUB
6      6       3000      5      AUB
8      6       3500      6      AUB
```

So in fact it doesn't use both crew_id and type, it just uses type.

Here is how I solved this problem (probably there is a more elegant way to do it than use two nested 'CASE's, but you get the idea):

```
SELECT id,
    amount,
    CASE crew_id 
        WHEN @curCrewId THEN
            CASE type 
                WHEN @curType THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1
            END
        ELSE @curRow :=1
    END AS rank,
    @curCrewId := crew_id AS crew_id,
    @curType := type AS type
FROM Table1 p
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curCrewId := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY crew_id, type
```

The main idea remain. I just added a variable @curCrewId. If someone need to use 3 variables for grouping, so just use 3 variables and 3 nested 'CASE's. :)

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer ! Just an improvement : there is no need for JOIN clause as the variables are initialized in SELECT clause.

Comment: @BenL It doesn't work without JOIN. Unfortunately I can't explain it correctly, but you can just try it:)

Comment: This doesn't work if the rows in the table are not ordered by crew_id & type. To fix this I added a sub query: `FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY crew_id, type) p`

Comment: Just to add up to this answer, if you use a slightly modified syntax for the `CASE` statement you can compare all your grouping columns on one `CASE` without needing nesting, like this: `CASE WHEN @curCrewId = crew_id AND @curType = type THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 ELSE @curRow := 1 END`

Answer (score 46):

Please go through my fiddle

[This One Last Tried](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5819/6)

```
    SELECT    id,
              crew_id,
              amount,
              type,
             ( 
                CASE type 
                WHEN @curType 
                THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := type END
              ) + 1 AS rank
    FROM      Table1 p,
              (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
   ORDER BY  crew_id,type asc;
```

Comment: Is possible to include crew_id? can you rank it according to crew_id and AUB?

Comment: There is a slight issue with this. If the type starts with a number the rank starts at 2 instead of 1. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @SystemParadox take the `+ 1` out from `) + 1 AS rank`

Comment: What is the `(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r` part for?

Comment: Som, the syntax `tblTable1, tblTable2` results in a `CROSS JOIN` being performed on the two tables.  This is where each row from `tblTable1` is reproduced with *each* row from `tblTable2` added on (read up on `CROSS JOIN`'s for more).  In this case the equivalent of `tblTable2` has just one row, which results in `@curRow` and `@curType` being added as fields to `tblTable1`'s equivalent (`Table1`), with the field values always being `0` and `''`.  This part also initialises the *variables* `@curRow` and `@curType` to `0` and `''`, respectively.

Answer (score 17):

With MySQL 8.0 you can use the window function ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY crew_id) AS row_number
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This is just perfect for what I was looking for. I added an order by within the PARTITION clause and it was perfect to number rows within groups.

Comment: ^^This is the answer

Answer (score 4):

@Janty's answer does not work when the type starts with a number (the rank starts at 2 instead of 1).

Use the following instead:

```
SELECT id,
     crew_id,
     amount,
     CASE type 
         WHEN @curType THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
         ELSE @curRow := 1
     END AS rank,
     @curType := type AS type
FROM Table1 p
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY crew_id, type
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer of @Janty here is a solution if you want to UDATE your table with the rownumber:

```
UPDATE myTable mt,(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r SET type=
    ( 
        CASE type 
            WHEN @curType
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := type END
      )
;
```

As janty too crewId is not within. Use a second "case" for that as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: how to add order by clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, crew_id, amount, type,
       ( 
        CASE type 
          WHEN @curType 
          THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
          ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := type  END
      ) + 1 AS rank
 FROM      Table1 p,
      (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
   ORDER BY  crew_id, type asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer using only *one case* that creates row number according to *both columns*:

```
SELECT id, crew_id, amount, type,
   (CASE CONCAT(crew_id, type) 
        WHEN @cur_crew_type
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
        ELSE @curRow := 0 END) + 1 AS cnt,
    @cur_crew_type := CONCAT(crew_id, type) AS cur_crew_type
FROM TABLE t,
     (SELECT @curRow := 0, @cur_crew_type := '') counter
      ORDER BY crew_id, type;
```