# Times between laps

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL work fine except 1 point (at third value I need take previous time), this is the table (times) schema, output, and SQL:

```
id        number    time
-----------------------------------
1         9        00:00:10.000000
2         10       00:00:15.000000
3         9        00:00:22.000000
4         10       00:00:35.000000
1         9        00:00:55.000000

SELECT t.number, COUNT(1) laps, 
GROUP_CONCAT(SEC_TO_TIME(time) ORDER BY t.id) times
  FROM (
        SELECT t1.id, t1.number, 
        TIME_TO_SEC(t1.time) - COALESCE(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.time)), 0) time
        FROM times t1 
  LEFT JOIN times t2 ON t1.number = t2.number AND t2.id < t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number, t1.time
) t
GROUP BY number
```

Result this output:

```
number    laps     times
-----------------------------------
9         3        00:00:10,00:00:12,00:00:23
10        2        00:00:15,00:00:20
```

I need this REsult expected:

```
number    laps     times
-----------------------------------
9         3        00:00:10,00:00:12,00:00:33
10        2        00:00:15,00:00:20
```

Where third time - previos calculated time, in this case (00:00:10,00:00:12,00:00:23 - 00:00:12) I Tried but SUM all times previous.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1495e/1)

Comment: The last id should be 5 according to your sql fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only need change `SUM` to `MAX`

```
SELECT t.number, COUNT(1) laps, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SEC_TO_TIME(time) ORDER BY t.id) times
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.number, 
    TIME_TO_SEC(t1.time) - COALESCE(MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.time)), 0) time
  FROM times t1 
  LEFT JOIN times t2 ON t1.number = t2.number AND t2.time < t1.time  -- Suggest you don't use id to compare
  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number, t1.time
) t
GROUP BY number
```

See <kbd>[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1495e/46/0)</kbd>

And here's another version without inner group by. They have the same effect, but different query plan. So you have choices to compare the performances.

```
SELECT t.number, COUNT(1) laps, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SEC_TO_TIME(time) ORDER BY t.time) times
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.number, t1.time tm1,
    (SELECT  TIME_TO_SEC(t1.time) - COALESCE(MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.time)),0) 
       FROM times t2 
      WHERE t1.number = t2.number AND t2.time < t1.time) AS time
  FROM times t1 
) t
GROUP BY number;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit tricky, but here is a solution:

The main problem is the "smaller than" condition in your join. So first you have to add a running number (rank) to your Groups based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql). Then you can join by that rank. The resulting query is a bit large but gives you the desired result:

```
SELECT t.number, COUNT(1) laps,
GROUP_CONCAT(SEC_TO_TIME(time) ORDER BY t.id) times
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.number,
        TIME_TO_SEC(t1.time) - COALESCE(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.time)), 0) time
    FROM
    (SELECT
        number, id, time,
        (
            CASE number
            WHEN @curType
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := number END
        ) AS rank
    FROM times, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
    ORDER BY  number, id
    ) as t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        number, id, time,
        (
            CASE number
            WHEN @curType
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := number END
        ) AS rank
    FROM times, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
    ORDER BY  number, id
    ) t2
    ON t1.number = t2.number and t2.rank+1 = t1.rank
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number, t1.time
) t
GROUP BY number
```

gives:

```
| NUMBER | LAPS |                      TIMES |
|--------|------|----------------------------|
|      9 |    3 | 00:00:10,00:00:12,00:00:33 |
|     10 |    2 |          00:00:15,00:00:20 |
```