# increment numbers on each group of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

The table below represents the data I have in a table.

```
+----+------+
| ID | Year |
+----+------+
|  1 | 2005 |
|  1 | 2006 |
|  2 | 2005 |
|  2 | 2007 |
|  2 | 2008 |
|  3 | 2005 |
|  4 | 2009 |
+----+------+
```

I want to write a query which will show the results below.

```
+----+----+------+
| ID |auto| Year |
+----+----+------+
|  1 |  1 | 2005 |
|  1 |  2 | 2006 |
|  2 |  1 | 2005 |
|  2 |  2 | 2007 |
|  2 |  3 | 2008 |
|  3 |  1 | 2005 |
|  4 |  1 | 2009 |
+----+----+------+
```

As you can see the `auto` field will display an increment auto numbering to each ID.

Comment: someone want to bang out a variables with grouping for this ? It is definitely a duplicate question x 1000

Comment: ...or slower...`SELECT x.* , COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id = x.id AND y.year <= x.year GROUP BY x.id,x.year;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row number per group in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql)

Comment: See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f7cd/11

Comment: true that ↑ as it is my current hammer and everything is a nail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  if(@i = id, @n:=@n+1, @n:=1) auto, @i:=id id, year 
    from thetable cross join (select @i:="") i cross join (select @n:=1) n 
  order by id, year
```

Comment: Variables are the right approach, but if you use them, then they should all go into a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

Comment: @Drew i see there the result from the question

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: but it is the wrong and dangerous approach as @GordonLinoff said. Read [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this in MySQL is to use variables.  But, if you use variables, all the assignments need to be in the same expression because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

So I recommend:

```
select id, 
       (@rn := if(@i = id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@i := id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as auto,
       year
from tableX cross join
     (select @i := -1, @rn := 0) params
order by id, year;
```

Comment: removed possible 1064 error (Gordon types fast), reshuffled columns, this matches desired results, and is the safe way to do it without assuming variables are as you think they are, as Gordon said above in comments.