# Chat App - List 10 latest messages from each chat on page load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a chat app with multiple chats in one page. Each chat I want to get the latest 10 messages to load first (and then lazy load the older ones if they want them) when the page loads.

I want to use the `whereIn` that laravel offers so I can get multiple chat groups in a single query.

My current code is:

```
$chats = ChatMessage::whereIn('group_id', $group_ids)->orderBy('message_date', 'ASC')->take(10)->get();
```

But I realize that the `take(10)` only takes 10. I want to take 10 for every group_id in the table.

What is the most efficient way to do this in laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do that unless you perform a different query for each chat. In mysql you need use variable to tag each row in the category with a `row_number` first

Use something like this [Row number per group in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql) and then perform your query over that result where `row_number <= 10`