# add column and fill with ascending numbers based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table

```
id      secId
 1          2
 2          2
 3          2
 4          1
 5          3
 6          3
```

i would like to add a new column "sortIndex" and init it's values to an ascending int value for each set of equal secId's.
So the resulting table would be

```
id      secId       sortIndex
 1          2               1
 2          2               2
 3          2               3
 4          1               1
 5          3               1
 6          3               2
```

So for every set of equal secId's I have a new sequence "1,2,3,4,..."
If there is any chance a single query would be just awesome.

Comment: You want to emulate the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` which MySQL is lacking. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Then I would have to first create a new column for sortIndex and then use the info in your pasted link to update the sortIndex-entries?

Comment: You shouldn't add a column for data which is implicitely already there. Create row numbers on-the-fly when you need them (that's only for display; you don't need them for mere sorting, as you can just as well order by id).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yeah - no :-) Not in my case. I need the sort_index column to provide a manual sorting possibility for data in a frontend. This is a feature just implemented and therefore already existing db's have to be adapted and  need to provide some initial ordering by the column "sort_index". So - I really do need this column to be inserted in an existing table and be auto-filled with sequences of ascending numbers.

Comment: Ah, okay, it's an initial sort oeder that can be changed later. Okay. If I remember correctly, MySQL has problems with accessing the same table in an update statement, so you may want to create a table temporarily (`create temp_table (id_secid, sortindex) select id, secid, @rownum ...`) and use this then to update your existing table (where you add the new column first of course).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner OK, that sounds reasonable. However - being not that deep in MySql I struggle applying your suggestion. Could you refine / make it more specific what I have to do and how the syntax could be?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to simulate row_number in MySQL. You need to use variable.

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @sec_id:='';
SELECT id, @row_number:=CASE WHEN @secid=secid THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number, 
@secid:=secid AS secid
FROM your_table
ORDER BY secid;
```

You can find more details at

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number.

Check for `secId`, if its same increment the `@curRow` by `1`.

**Query**

```
select Id,secId,( 
  case secId 
  when @curA
  then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
  else @curRow := 1 and @curA := secId end
) as sort_index
from your_table_name t,
(select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r
order by Id,secId;
```

### [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9cc27/1)

Comment: Thx, but this throws a couple of errors - what are the brackets around the second select for and what means the "r" in this same row?
Also why is there a mapping for the table "your_table" to "t" if t is never used?
And - what is the comma doing after "t"?
Then - is this query meant to be used after a new column "sort_index" was created already?

Comment: @user3440145 : `t` and `r` are just aliases.

Comment: @user3440145: The comma between tables (the comma after t) is an antiquated join syntax. You can replace it with `CROSS JOIN` to make the join explicit.