# How to query the index for each record based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a order table which i would like to index each company's first second third ... etc order.

Example of table:

```
|---------------------|--------------------------|
|      company_id     |     created_at           |
|---------------------|--------------------------|
|          1          |   2019-01-01 01:00:00    |
|---------------------|--------------------------|
|          1          |   2019-02-01 01:00:00    |
|---------------------|--------------------------|
|          2          |   2019-03-01 02:00:00    |
|---------------------|--------------------------|
|          3          |   2019-03-01 08:30:00    |
|---------------------|--------------------------|
|          2          |   2019-03-01 10:00:00    |
|---------------------|--------------------------|
```

I Would it be queried like this in the end. but im not sure how..... i keep going back to counting and grouping the fields but i cant seem to get the sum for each row  based on the timestamp

```
|---------------------|--------------------------|-------|
|      company_id     |     created_at           |count()|
|---------------------|--------------------------|--------
|          1          |   2019-01-01 01:00:00    |   1   |
|---------------------|--------------------------|--------
|          1          |   2019-02-01 01:00:00    |   2   |
|---------------------|--------------------------|--------
|          2          |   2019-03-01 02:00:00    |   1   |
|---------------------|--------------------------|--------
|          3          |   2019-03-01 08:30:00    |   1   |
|---------------------|--------------------------|--------
|          2          |   2019-03-01 10:00:00    |   2   |
|---------------------|--------------------------|--------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row number per group in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @company_id = company_id THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS count1,
    @company_id:=company_id as company_id,
    created_at
FROM
    Table1,(SELECT @company_id:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
ORDER BY company_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84c6d3/2)

Comment: how does @row_number actually work ?  im not familiar with using @ in sql

Comment: Napmi : you are initializing a variable @row_number with 0 to start you count for company_id. Just saying: your answer query (for the same question) will be more time consuming

Comment: i believe you are right about the time consuming part. as my order table increases in size , im gonna be screwed by my query.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in the end was as below , which seems more simplier than the above has suggested.

```
SELECT company_id
,(
    SELECT count(*) + 1
    FROM ORDERS AS orderCount
    WHERE orderCount.company_id = orders.company_id
        AND orderCount.created_at < orders.created_at
    ) AS order_count
FROM ORDERS
ORDER BY created_at
```