# Aggregate data over multiple fields (not records)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id | segment1 |segment2|segment3|segment4|**FREQUENT**
1  | A        | B      | A      | A      | A
2  | B        | C      | C      | C      | C
```

Need to find the most frequent letters from segment1 |segment2|segment3|segment4| i.e to find column  FREQUENT.

Comment: helps will be highly appreciated

Comment: **Everyone** here asking a question wants help as soon as possible. Nobody gets to decide that their own problem is more urgent than anyone else's.

Comment: I would say it is a task for a trigger. Pure SQL solution will be terribly sophisticated.

Comment: Hey @30thh possible or not?

Comment: Yes it is. But I don't think you will like the result ☺️. I added the needed steps to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to copy all the segments into a single column. One can do it using UNION or a temporary table.

Then you need to count the frequency grouping the result by ID.

Then you need to get the most frequent value in every group. It can be done using self joining over LEFT JOIN or using ordering and row numbering by group. It is the most complicated part. See

[Row number per group in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql/17939679)

Then you filter by the row number and enjoy the result.